# Highslide slideshow auto - display controls

Tags: highslide

I have Highslide (4.1.13) working happily in a number of sites, including slideshows and individual expanding images, and would like to stick with it.

But what I would ideally like to do with a slideshow is to start it in auto mode but then to display controls if a user hovers over or clicks on an image - effectively allowing an 'interrupt' to switch into manual mode if the user wants to pause on an image or to go back. Is there any way to do this or has anyone found a reasonable workaround?

Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How close does this come to what you're after? The slide show starts automatically if you click any thumbnail (and it could be set to start automatically upon page load), the controls appear if you hover, which gives you a "pause" button, and if you click the image for "next" or click the "previous" or "next" arrows, it goes to the next (or previous) image and pauses the slideshow.

http://earlyout.org/autoslide

All the "magic" is in the config file: http://earlyout.org/autoslide/res/hsconfig.js